# What is the MVC program flow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a good description the the flow of events (life cycle) of what happens after I type in my application's url in the browser to when the page is actually displayed. Does anyone have one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [ASP.NET MVC Request Handling Pipeline poster](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/be_ahead_of_the_game_poster1.htm) by [Steve Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/) that might help.